# Disappearing form fields on IE?

Tags: browser, cross-browser

I have been working on this site for some time and just launched it for a client.
People have actually had trouble beleiving I had done it on WordPress, though I don't see why...

Anyway, I suddenly see that the form fields of one of the forms on the site (Newsletter Registration) disappear while on IE, you get to see them for a second and puff, they're gone. I did check this previously on IE and it worked, I especially used [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to get the rounded effect for the fields on IE...

Link to website: http://www.doritsivan.com (hope this isn't considered promotion, not my intention)
site is based on WordPress and  jQuery.

Comment: Why is that a WordPress question? Sounds more like JavaScript/CSS issue to me.

Comment: Actually you're probably right, I put it here because I've been so into wordpress lately and the site is on wordpress, so it seemed logical to me when I did it... Is there anyway to ask for a "Question Transfer"?

Comment: I'll do it, but you should improve your question. Add at least an URI with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved the issue, thank you all. it was a bad case of relative vs. absolute positioning and the fields decided to go away (literaly) 
A bunch of debugging with firebug-lite (btw was real to get it to work on my IE, kept on crashing or refusing to load altogether combined with IE popup and security issues) and I understoid that this was the issue, then some pixel fiddling and all was good. rechecked in Chrome, saw that result was exactly the same. job done